# script to monitor system information: date and time, CPU usage and memory

Tags: linux, bash, ubuntu, virtual-machine, virtualbox

Through linux, I am trying to make a shell script called monitornsusystem.sh that will append system related information to the file: systemstatus.log. The system information I need to append is: current date and time, CPU utilization as a percentage and system memory in use as a percentage. I can get all the right information from individual commands but when I put them together in a script, it just displays what's in the parenthesis, but it doesn't run any of the commands.

```
#!/bin/bash
sysstat=echo “date +'%d/%m/%Y %H:%M:%S' \
| echo $[100-$(vmstat 1 2|tail -1|awk '{print $15}’)]% \
| free \
| grep Mem \
| awk '{print $3/$2 * 100.0}’” >> systemstatus.log
```

Comment: We need to see an example of what you're expecting for output. Also, check your script at http://shellcheck.net . Good luck..

Comment: Piping the output of `echo` into `echo` is not useful. Piping data to `free` is also not useful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Divide and conquer... Put every value in a line and in the last line, show all the values. Something like this:

```
#!/bin/bash

mdate=`date +'%d/%m/%Y %H:%M:%S'`
mcpu=$[100-$(vmstat 1 2|tail -1|awk '{print $15}')]%
mmem=`free | grep Mem | awk '{print $3/$2 * 100.0}'`
echo "$mdate | $mcpu | $mmem" >> /tmp/sysstatus
```

Comment: #!/bin/bash
mdate= date +'%d/%m/%Y %H:%M:%S'
mcpu= echo $[100-$(vmstat 1 2|tail -1|awk '{print $15}’)]%
mmem= free | grep Mem | awk '{print $3/$2 * 100.0}'
final= echo “$mdate | $mcpu | $mmem” >> /home/daniel/systemstatus.log

Thanks so much for the feedback, I posted my final script above but when I run the script monitornsusystem.sh, it does output those 3 system informations I need but when I run “cat /home/daniel/systemstatus.log” for where I appended it to, I get “date +'%d/%m/%Y %H:%M:%S' | echo $[100-$(vmstat 1 2|tail -1|awk '{print $15}’)]% | free | grep Mem | awk ' ect.

Comment: Why don't you use my code? you are piping vmstat output to the free util, and that doesn't make sense, because free not will process that info. You must be cautious with the use of '|'.